# NativeScript/Angular list-picker looks strange with black above and below - what's wrong?

Tags: native, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm creating a NativeScript/Angular mobile application, and trying to include a list-picker in a form.

1. What is causing the black background above and below the selected item in my list-picker? How can I make the background transparent?
2. The selected item area is very small - how can I enlarge it?

Screenshot below:

[image]

Here's my list-picker code:

```
<ListPicker #picker class="picker" [items]="viewData.phoneTypes" [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center" (selectedIndexChange)="selectedIndexChanged(picker)"></ListPicker>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please get familiar with the posting-questions guidelines - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please share code you consider relevant so others may better understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: @pkanev - added code, thanks

Comment: To answer question 1, have you tried setting the z-index of the `ListPicker` element in CSS?

Comment: As for Q2, you might want to post more of the code, so we can see what's going on, but again, this will likely be a css fix: e.g.  `ListPicker { width: 50% }`